# how could I create a Scanner object again after I have executed its close() method?

Tags: java, exception, runtime-error, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

when I inputed secondly it thorowed `java.util.NoSuchElementException`, if I want to use Scanner again after I close the sc, how should I do? 
Another question: How do I close an Scanner object created under another java file in the main method?

```
package test;        
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i);
        sc.close();

        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int j = sc2.nextInt();
        System.out.println(j);
        sc2.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1.**

Using multiple Scanners is a bad practice.

You can use the same Scanner to do all of your tasks.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(i);

    int j = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(j);

    sc.close();
```

**Q2.**

If you want to use Scanner in multiple classes, you can do like following

```
static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Create static Scanner in one class. And then you can import and use it from other classes.